# Can not run Apache Geronimo 3 on WinXP

Tags: jakarta-ee, windows-xp, geronimo

I get a `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException` when I'm trying to run Geronimo 3.0-M1 (with Tomcat) on Windows XP via `bin/geronino run` command. There is reportedly not any AES implementation. But if I try run simple application using AES, it works. I had a look on Internet, but nothing have found. Is there anybody with the same experience? *(Geronimo output follows.)*

```
C:\g\bin>geronimo run
Using GERONIMO_HOME:   C:\g
Using GERONIMO_TMPDIR: var\temp
Using JRE_HOME:        c:\Program files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21

  Apache Geronimo (3.0-M1)

geronimo> Booting Geronimo Kernel (in Java 1.6.0_21)...
Starting Geronimo Application Server v3.0-M1
[****                                    ]  12%   0s  Loading org.apache.ger...2011-02-25 18:23:33,000 ERROR [AbstractEncryption] Unable to decrypt
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
        at org.apache.geronimo.crypto.AbstractEncryption.decrypt(AbstractEncryption.java:74)
        at org.apache.geronimo.crypto.EncryptionManager.decrypt(EncryptionManager.java:108)
        at org.apache.geronimo.system.plugin.PluginRepositoryDownloader.loadUserRepositories(PluginRepositoryDownloader.java:122)
        at org.apache.geronimo.system.plugin.PluginRepositoryDownloader.<init>(PluginRepositoryDownloader.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ReflectionUtil$ConstructorFactory.create(ReflectionUtil.java:952)
        at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ObjectRecipe.internalCreate(ObjectRecipe.java:276)
        at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:96)
        at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:61)
        at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:917)
        at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:269)
        at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:103)
        at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.startRecursive(GBeanInstanceState.java:125)
        at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.startRecursive(GBeanInstance.java:544)
        at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startRecursiveGBean(BasicKernel.java:386)
        at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:461)
        at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.start(KernelConfigurationManager.java:224)
        at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:698)
        at org.apache.geronimo.system.main.EmbeddedDaemon.doStartup(EmbeddedDaemon.java:189)
        at org.apache.geronimo.system.main.EmbeddedDaemon.execute(EmbeddedDaemon.java:88)
        at org.apache.geronimo.system.osgi.BootActivator$1.execute(BootActivator.java:107)
        at org.apache.geronimo.main.Bootstrapper.execute(Bootstrapper.java:65)
        at org.apache.geronimo.cli.AbstractCLI.executeMain(AbstractCLI.java:65)
        at org.apache.geronimo.cli.daemon.DaemonCLI.main(DaemonCLI.java:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem on Linux. I use JRE instead JDK to run Geronimo and it works.

```
Using GERONIMO_HOME:   /usr/devel/geronimo-tomcat6-javaee5-2.2
Using GERONIMO_TMPDIR: var/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/devel/jre1.6.0_24
Booting Geronimo Kernel (in Java 1.6.0_24)...
Starting Geronimo Application Server v2.2
[****************************************] 100%  28s Startup complete
```

I have set system variables in this way:

```
JRE_HOME=/usr/devel/jre1.6.0_24
JAVA_HOME=/usr/devel/jdk1.6.0_24
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither the JDK nor the JRE works on my WinXP instance. Geronimo runs on my company notebook with JRE and WinXP properly. I have to give it up. I'm spending too much time on it without needing it.

Comment: I am also getting error as `ERROR [AbstractEncryption] Unable to decrypt
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES`